# Finding Consistent estimator

Tags: probability, parameter-estimation

Let $X_1,X_2,......X_n$ be a random sample from a population density function

$ f_\theta(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} \frac{4}{\theta}x^3e^{\frac{-x^4}{\theta}}, \quad x>0, \\ \\ 0,  \quad \text{otherwise} \end{array} \right.$

where $\theta >0$ is unknown. Then , a consistent estimator for $\theta$ is

I know to find consistency of a given estimator. Since there is no estimator given in the question should we find a consistency estimator? if so how do we find it ?

Comment: I don't understand your concern in the last line. Do you have any idea what a 'reasonable' estimator of $\theta$ could be? (typo in the pdf; should be $x>0$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per MLE properties, $\hat{\theta}_{ML}$ is consistent

So, simply let's define

$$L(\theta)\propto \frac{1}{\theta^n}e^{-\frac{\sum x^4}{\theta}}$$

$$log L=-nlog\theta-\frac{\sum x^4}{\theta}$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial{\theta}}log L=-\frac{n}{\theta}+\frac{\sum x^4}{\theta^2}$$

$$\hat{\theta}_{ML}=\frac{\sum x^4}{n}$$

which is the same solution as the above topic

Answer (score 0):

If you would try to compute the fourth moment of the random variable $X$, you will find,

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[X^4] &= \int_{0}^{\infty}x^4f(x)dx \\
 &=\int_{0}^{\infty}\tfrac{4}{\theta}x^7e^{\tfrac{x^4}{\theta}}dx. \\
&= \theta\int_{0}^{\infty}y \cdot e^{-y}dx \hspace{3mm} (\text{taking transformation }y =\tfrac{x^4}{\theta} )\\
& = \theta \cdot \mathbb{E}[Y] \\
&= \theta \hspace{3mm}(\text{since } Y \sim \text{Exp}(1))
\end{align}

So a natural estimator would be the sample analogue of the fourth moment, i.e.
$\hat{\theta}_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^4$. By the weak law of large number we then have:
\begin{align}
\hat{\theta}_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{E}[X^4] = \theta
\end{align}

Comment: How did u came to intuition that we should compute fourth moment?

Comment: That is basically just intuition. Usually if you have some ugly powers in the exponential function, you would like to transform it to something that will make the integral yield an analytic solution. I tried $\mathbb{E}[X]$ first but that didn't seem to work out. Then $\mathbb{E}[X^4]$ came quite naturally. I hope this helps!